# What are the brass contacts inside domestic AC power plugs and sockets called?

Tags: plug, socket, terminal

I've been hunting high and low across the internet, but I haven't had any luck so far.

What I need:

Brass terminals/contacts that can be soldered on a PCB and will receive electrical plugs. I want it to be able to receive plugs of all standards. What I'm looking for are terminals like these, but PCB mounted:[image]

I can't find them anywhere, and I don't even know what to search for.

Edit:

I am looking for contacts that can be soldered onto PCBs, not complete housings. I need to produce a couple hundred of these PCBs, and the PCB must interface with the electrical plug directly.

Comment: Maybe electrodes. Your picture also shows a fuse holder. These can be bought PCB style.

Comment: There are quite a few around that can be soldered to PCBs, but in housings. Do you want the contacts only?

Comment: Yes, I want the contacts only.

Comment: I've always called them "contacts", although some folks might call them "terminals".  No doubt the manufacturers have terms for the internal features -- eg, the "fingers" that surround a pin might be called "wipers".

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an IEC inlet or outlet for this?  C13/C14 is ubiquitous worldwide -- just ask for a "computer power cord".

Answer (score 1):

AC plugs can be used with adapters. The adapters allow a UK style plug to fit in a US wall socket or a French wall socket and vice versa. You normally see them for sale at airports.

So, get yourself a bunch of adapters to suit the wall socket of your choice then buy a wall socket that is compatible with being soldered to a PCB. If it needs to be a regular wall socket on a flying lead then is this going to be a problem?

Maybe get one of these: -

[image]

From [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/5-Pieces-Desk-Top-socket-Free-shipping-Pearl-chromium-multi-function-power-outlet-network-cat6-or/506892020.html)